# React native WebView URL

Tags: android, react-native, webview

I am facing a problem with retrieving current URL from WebView. Currently, I am using the following method get the URL

```
onNavigationStateChange()
```

Recently noticed that URL is deprecated! I need to use source prop to get the URL. But I couldn't figure it out. Also, the function above gets called twice. Is there any way to get URL in `loadingFinished()` function?

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take use of [onNavigationStateChange](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onnavigationstatechange). On **Navigation state change**, update `state`. And use `url` from `state` whenever required.

Code:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, WebView } from 'react-native';

const initialUrl = 'https://github.com';
let url = '';

export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    url: initialUrl,
  };

  onNavigationStateChange = navState => {
    if (url!==navState.url) { 
      url = navState.url;
      alert(url);
      this.setState({
        url: url
      })
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { url } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{paddingTop: 24, flex: 1}}>
        <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'black', color: 'white'}}>{ url }</Text>
        <WebView
        style={{ flex: 1}}
          source={{
            uri: initialUrl,
          }}
          onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
          startInLoadingState
          scalesPageToFit
          javaScriptEnabled
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Live example on snack https://snack.expo.io/SyRNRLj-G

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can access URL from onNavigationStateChange but I believe that URL is deprecated as the documentation says. Am I wrong?

Comment: `url` prop is deprecated. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.9/webview.html#url. We can get current url from state, it is not deprecated. So you can go with the above solution.